# I want to use web scraping to read the information within each record here

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to extract the following information from each mission in this website:

https://aad.archives.gov/aad/display-partial-records.jsp?dt=1802&sc=23947%2C23905%2C23906%2C23880%2C23907%2C23889%2C23890%2C23892%2C23893%2C23894&cat=all&tf=F&bc=%2Csl%2Cfd&q=&as_alq=&as_anq=&as_epq=&as_woq=&nfo_23947=V%2C1%2C1900&cl_23947=&nfo_23905=V%2C25%2C1900&op_23905=0&txt_23905=&nfo_23906=V%2C2%2C1900&cl_23906=03&nfo_23880=D%2C6%2C1966&op_23880=3&txt_23880=&txt_23880=&nfo_23907=D%2C6%2C1966&op_23907=3&txt_23907=&txt_23907=&nfo_23889=V%2C10%2C1900&op_23889=0&txt_23889=&nfo_23890=V%2C10%2C1900&op_23890=0&txt_23890=&nfo_23892=V%2C1%2C1900&cl_23892=E%2CX%2CA%2C7%2C%3D%2CQ%2CR%2CI%2C3%2CV&nfo_23893=V%2C2%2C1900&cl_23893=J0&nfo_23894=N%2C5%2C1900&op_23894=6&txt_23894=0&txt_23894=&rpp=50

- OPERATION NAME
- OPERATION TYPE CODE
- MAJOR PROVINCE CODE
- UTM MAP COORDINATE
- NUMBER DESTROYED OF KILLED

Using `rvest` I have tried to extract the href for each mission under View Record but am not getting much luck

```
 results <- read_html("https://aad.archives.gov/aad/display-partial-records.jsp?dt=1802&sc=23947%2C23905%2C23906%2C23880%2C23907%2C23889%2C23890%2C23892%2C23893%2C23894&cat=all&tf=F&bc=%2Csl%2Cfd&q=&as_alq=&as_anq=&as_epq=&as_woq=&nfo_23947=V%2C1%2C1900&cl_23947=&nfo_23905=V%2C25%2C1900&op_23905=0&txt_23905=&nfo_23906=V%2C2%2C1900&cl_23906=03&nfo_23880=D%2C6%2C1966&op_23880=3&txt_23880=&txt_23880=&nfo_23907=D%2C6%2C1966&op_23907=3&txt_23907=&txt_23907=&nfo_23889=V%2C10%2C1900&op_23889=0&txt_23889=&nfo_23890=V%2C10%2C1900&op_23890=0&txt_23890=&nfo_23892=V%2C1%2C1900&cl_23892=E%2CX%2CA%2C7%2C%3D%2CQ%2CR%2CI%2C3%2CV&nfo_23893=V%2C2%2C1900&cl_23893=J0&nfo_23894=N%2C5%2C1900&op_23894=6&txt_23894=0&txt_23894=")
  

missions_url <- results %>% 
  html_nodes("tbody td:nth-child(1)") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Please tell me how I can extract the information as detailed above. Thank you.

Comment: Because of the javascript functionality in this page you will need to use Selenium (see https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/) to scrape the results from this site. While you may see the full results when you load the url in your OP in the browser, when you load it with `rvest::read_html` all you get is: `<body>\n<br><br><div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: center;">Searching...Please Wait.</div>\n</body>
>`

Comment: @br00t thank you for your reply. How do I use RSelenium to then scrape the results from this site?

Comment: SO ist not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do it with the following code :

```
library(rvest)
library(RDCOMClient)

url <- "https://aad.archives.gov/aad/display-partial-records.jsp?dt=1802&sc=23947%2C23905%2C23906%2C23880%2C23907%2C23889%2C23890%2C23892%2C23893%2C23894&cat=all&tf=F&bc=%2Csl%2Cfd&q=&as_alq=&as_anq=&as_epq=&as_woq=&nfo_23947=V%2C1%2C1900&cl_23947=&nfo_23905=V%2C25%2C1900&op_23905=0&txt_23905=&nfo_23906=V%2C2%2C1900&cl_23906=03&nfo_23880=D%2C6%2C1966&op_23880=3&txt_23880=&txt_23880=&nfo_23907=D%2C6%2C1966&op_23907=3&txt_23907=&txt_23907=&nfo_23889=V%2C10%2C1900&op_23889=0&txt_23889=&nfo_23890=V%2C10%2C1900&op_23890=0&txt_23890=&nfo_23892=V%2C1%2C1900&cl_23892=E%2CX%2CA%2C7%2C%3D%2CQ%2CR%2CI%2C3%2CV&nfo_23893=V%2C2%2C1900&cl_23893=J0&nfo_23894=N%2C5%2C1900&op_23894=6&txt_23894=0&txt_23894=&rpp=50"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(10)
doc <- IEApp$document()
web_Obj_Table <- doc$getElementByID("queryResults")
html_Content <- read_html(doc$Body()$innerHtml())
list_Html_Table <- html_table(html_Content)
list_Html_Table[[2]]

# A tibble: 51 × 11
   `View Record` `FORCE NATIONALITY` `OPERATION NAME`   `MAJOR PROVINCE CODE` `INITIATION DATE` `TERMINATION DATE` `BRIGADE DESIGNATION` `DIVISION DESIGNATION` `LOSS NATIONALITY`
   <lgl>         <chr>               <chr>              <chr>                 <chr>             <chr>              <chr>                 <chr>                  <chr>             
 1 NA            ""                  ""                 ""                    ""                ""                 ""                    ""                     ""                
 2 NA            "RVN"               "NGU HOANH SON"    "Quang Nam"           "10/22/2065"      ""                 ""                    ""                     "RVN"             
 3 NA            "Marine"            "SUWANNEE"         "Quang Nam"           "08/13/1966"      ""                 "9  MAR"              "3  MAR"               "RVN"             
 4 NA            "RVN"               "HOA TUYEN 147"    "Quang Nam"           "08/19/1966"      "08/27/1966"       ""                    ""                     "RVN"             
 5 NA            "RVN"               "HOA TUYEN 149"    "Quang Nam"           "09/01/1966"      ""                 "51 INF"              "2  INF"               "RVN"             
 6 NA            "RVN"               "HOA TUYEN 149"    "Quang Nam"           "09/01/1966"      "09/04/1966"       "INF"                 "2  INF"               "RVN"             
 7 NA            "RVN"               "HOA TUYEN 153"    "Quang Nam"           "09/19/1966"      "09/24/1966"       ""                    ""                     "RVN"             
 8 NA            "RVN"               "TAO THANH DUY"    "Quang Nam"           "09/24/1966"      "09/26/1966"       ""                    ""                     "RVN"             
 9 NA            "RVN"               "HOA TUYEN 154"    "Quang Nam"           "09/30/1966"      ""                 ""                    ""                     "RVN"             
10 NA            "RVN"               "TRUY KICH TRD 51" "Quang Nam"           "10/16/1966"      ""                 "51 INF"              "2  INF"               "RVN"             
# ℹ 41 more rows
# ℹ 2 more variables: `LOSS CODE` <chr>, `NUMBER DESTROYED OF KILLED` <int>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```